# Right margin for table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I was trying for quite a while (with titlesec, toclof, etoc) to create a table of contents which looks like in the picture below (it's from smflatex) but I didn't succeed. Especially, I was not able to add a right margin. Does anyone know how to create such a neat toc?

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if you find it sufficient to solve your problem! (If you want to wait and see if anyone else has a better or more elegant solution then by all means :) )

Comment: Also! In the future, when you ask questions here, it's _really_ helpful if you provide runnable code! Like just any attempt you have :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't accept yet because the answer just addresses the margin problem (which was my primary issue), not the full style as in the picture. Also, I didn't provide runnable code because, well, nothing worked as I said.

Comment: You're really just asking for the margin in the question though? Maybe you should elaborate and be more detailed/specific, and you might get the answer you want :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the `article` documentclass, just put the ToC inside the abstract environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[4]
  \tableofcontents
\end{abstract}
\section{A}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}
\section{B}
\subsection{c}
\subsubsection{d}
\end{document}
```

If you don't want the `abstract`, environment, you could just use the `quotation` environment, which is what `abstract` uses to get the margins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{quotation}
  \lipsum[4]
  \tableofcontents
\end{quotation}
\section{A}
\end{document}
```

[image: such a neat toc]

Comment: This with the quotation environment is quite neat already, thanks!